# Add reaction to a message by ID discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to add a reaction to a message by message ID. For example, `messageID.react('')`. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answere:

`channelID.messages.fetch(MESSAGE_ID).then(function (message) { message.react("") })`

Answer (score 4):

`messages.fetch()` returns a promise. So in order to react to the message fetched, you can do it in two ways.

Using `.then()`:

```js
channel.messages.fetch(msg).then(m => {
    m.react("");
});
```

Using `await`:

```
const m = await channel.messages.fetch(msg);
m.react("");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the text channel the message is sent in, then you can just do:

```js
channel.messages.fetch(messageId).react("");
```

Comment: Got this error: 
`channel.messages.fetch(msg).react("�");
                                        ^
TypeError: channel.messages.fetch(...).react is not a function`

This is the code for the channel:  
`let channel = message.mentions.channels.first()
        if(!channel) return message.channel.send("❌ | Please tag a channel")`

Comment: Did you check to make sure that the message with the id actually exists in the channel?

Comment: Yes I did. [This](https://www.memebotdc.de/Pics/test1.jpg) is my code

Comment: You're checking to make sure that an ID is provided, but you're never checking to make sure the ID belongs to a message in the channel.